# With C++ type-traits, is there some way to avoid casting

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization, type-traits

Say I use C++ type-traits in a method template to check if T is double, is there some way I can treat variables of type T as double, without doing a cast?

```
T *l_double; //T is double 
if T is of type double 
   auto a = 5 * (*l_double);
```

(This will fail because T can be a non-number type, I could solve it by casting, but would like to avoid it).

Comment: What do you mean? Any example? If you are using only `double` why do you need a template ?

Comment: The whole point is that having done the type traits you can simply *assume* T is a double, or T is a bi-directional iterator, or whatever the type traits check is. Otherwise you write defensive template code that thinks "what if T is unsigned?" and similar questions.
In the other hand, simple template specialisation would probably work in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, what you want to have is a specialization for the case of `T` being `double`. Well, just do that - no type traits involved:

```
template <typename T>
void foo(T x) { /* do something with x */ }

template <>
void foo<double>(double x) { /* do something _else_ with x */ }
```

Or if you use C++17, you can also do:

```
template <typename T>
void foo(T x) { 
    if constexpr (not std::is_same_v<double,T>) {
        /* do something with x */ 
    }
    else {
        /* do something with else x */ 
    }
}
```

Note the `constexpr` after the `if`. That means the code within each block only gets compiled for the appropriate instantiations; without it, you can't use `x` as a double in the `else` block since that use would have to also work when `x` is of another type.

Comment: Wouldn't a simple overload `void foo(doube)` be better? I think there was a recommendation to not specialize template functions but to define overloads.

Comment: @Jens: I dunno... I mean, I like it that the specialization hints at the existence of the general, templated version.

Comment: @Jens - In this case it is actually a class template, so that would not work.  Specialization is probably slightly cleaner.

Comment: @einpoklum I found the article: http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill17.htm. I didn't remember all the details, but the overload resolution with function templates is interesting. But since `T` is actually a class template overloads don't work anyway.